# D modules over nodal curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules

Is there a simple description for $D$ modules over $\text{Spec}\left(k\left[x,y \right] / \left(xy\right) \right)$ (say k is algebraically closed of characteristic 0)? Is there a description of the $D$-module pushforward from its normalization?

Comment: The ($\infty$-categorical) theory of D-modules satisfies descent along proper surjective maps (see Gaitsgory-Rozenblyum “Crystals and D-modules”). For a nodal curve this implies that a D-module is equivalently a D-module on the normalization with identifications on the nodes

Answer (score 1):

If $C$ and $D$ are the two branches of the nodal curve, and $p\in C$ and $q\in D$ are the points that are identified to form $X=C\cup D$, then I think that a $\mathcal D$-module on $X$ consists of:

• A vector bundle $V$ with flat connection over $C$.
• A vector bundle $W$ with flat connection over $D$.
• A vector space $U$.

• A injective linear map $V\otimes \Omega^1_C|_{\{p\}}\to U$.
• A injective linear map $W\otimes \Omega^1_D|_{\{q\}}\to U$.

Comment: Why not general $\mathcal D$-modules on $C$ and $D$?

Comment: As @WillSawin points out, I think this is incorrect as stated. For example, how would one obtain a skyscraper D-module at a smooth point using this description?